# Laravel PasswordBroker::createToken() must implement interface

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to use Laravel `PasswordBroker` class to `createToken` without sending email. But when i call `createToken` method, it gives me this error.

```
Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\PasswordBroker::createToken() must implement interface Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\CanResetPassword, instance of stdClass given..
```

How can i call `createToken` method in my controller? As of now i'm using the code below but it gives me the error.

```
app('auth.password.broker')->createToken($customer);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your given object in this case `$customer` has to have an implementation of `CanResetPassword` which can be achieved extending `Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User` on your `$customer` object. I strongly recommend to give it an alias if your `$customer` object is called User as well.

```php
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable {}
```

Hope this helps and resolves your issues.